# Is there any codec to get thumbnail directly from a Image file?

Tags: image, thumbnails, codec, performance

I used gdi+'s Image class to decode image files.
But I found if I open a Image, then use GetThumbnail()Method, It is really slow, especially for high resolution images.

Is there any method for get a thumbnail faster?

Or is there any lib designed especially for fastly retriving thumbnails for most image formats.

Many thanks!

Thanks for mgr and PhiLho 's advices!!

I do use thumbs.db for a better user experience, and after open a image once, I stored its thumbnail stream into my own DB system for further usage.

The thing puzzled me is how to decode the Jpg, bmp, format images more faster, a decoder which do not get a total image but only a thumbnail. It have something to do with the image format.

I just want to know: are there any existing codecs libs written in C++ or C for doing this task.

Answer (score 2):

Can you cache the thumbnails as small image files alongside the main file?

Comment: Thank you! I've made a cache for store thumbnails with the image, of course, it makes no difference at the first time. So I need a lib which can decode images directly into thumbnails without decode total images. I mean I need a Image decoder.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by mgb, a cache is probably the solution: in Windows Explorer, when you switch to the move with image preview, it creates a system, hidden file named thumbs.db in the directory it displays. I think you can do something similar.

Or even better, force the creation and use such DB, since it is a standard. According to TriD, it is a "Generic OLE2 / Multistream Compound File".

Answer (score 0):

Regarding storing the thumbs in the DB you may take a look at [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: thanks! I do not use blob to store the images in DB, but write my own DB files for store the image file stream.